# What does it mean when the Animator "counts as" the Finger of God?

Tags: fluxx

In Monty Python Fluxx, the Animator reads:

> Counts as the Finger of God if the real Finger of God is not on the table.

1. Does it mean that the Animator has just the nominal value of the Finger of God or does it have its ability too?
2. Suppose I have the Animator and the Finger of God is not on the table. Someone plays a goal which requires the Finger of God. Am I 50% winning?
3. Suppose I have the Animator and the Finger of God is not on the table. Someone plays a goal which requires the Animator. Am I 50% winning or do I have to wait for someone to play the Finger of God so that my Animator is just the Animator again?

Answer (score 6):

It can count as the Finger of God **for the purposes of Goals AND for having the ability**.

That means:

1. I actually thought the answer was no, but in hunting for a source, I was corrected! So, **yes**, the card does have the Finger of God's ability as well. (The official FAQ seems to be down, but it was mentioned in [this post](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/2869545#2869545) on BGG.) This seems contrary to the game's aim of always having all the rules in effect visible on the cards on the table, but never mind.
2. **Yes**, the Animator counts as one of the required cards for any Goal which requires the Finger of God, so long as it isn't on the table somewhere else.
3. **The Animator is always acceptable for any Goal that requires the Animator**. It doesn't stop being the Animator even if it can also "count as" the Finger of God.

It's worth mentioning, however, that the Animator **cannot** be both the Animator and the Finger of God for the purposes of the Goal, "The Meaning of Life" (mentioned [further down](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/2885204#2885204) in that same forum).

Comment: @SirGalahad No problem. Glad I could help and welcome to the site! If you think an answer has answered your question, you can "accept" it by clicking the tick under the vote counter on the left of the answer. You can also up-vote helpful questions and answers all across the site to thank the contributors ([More info](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)). Enjoy your stay!